# Manage Session in the web config file using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have two sessions in my code:

Session["Email"] for user Login  Authentication

Session["prevUrl"] to remember last page visited

I want to know how to manage the session timeout in my webconfig file.  I only want the Session["Email"] to timeout so the user can be redirected to the last page visited when they log back in. At the moment both sessions are timing out after 1 min

Thanks

Web.config

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1">

</sessionState>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Code that runs when a new session is started  
if (Session["prevUrl"] != null)
{
  Response.Redirect((string)Session["prevUrl"]); //Will redirect to previous page visited
}
else
{
  //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires   
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
}
```

C# Page Load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["prevUrl"] = Request.Url;

        if (Session["Email"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force on Session key to expire. For this scenario you have to use Cache.

Comment: Hi Vijay any idea how to implement it using cache. I am new to session. Thanks

Comment: string userIdentifier = string.Empty;
            Cache.Add("Key" + userIdentifier, "Value 1", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);

Comment: Cache is shared among users, user Identifier here is to identity current user.